# Cannot retrieve similar record in list of objects

Tags: c#

I have a list of object which contains as `home_team` property string the following record "Inter", now the is that I'm obliged to use `Internazionale` as search parameter, so I did:

```
var fixId = fixtures.FirstOrDefault(c =>
                c.home_team.ToLower().Contains("internazionale") || 
                c.home_team.ToLower().StartsWith("internazionale".Substring(0, c.home_team.Length)));
```

but I got the following error:

> 'Index and length must refer to a position in the string. name: length '

Essentially I check if the team name is equal as the search parameter, which is `Internazionale`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will be the cause of the problem:

```
c.home_team.ToLower().StartsWith("internazionale".Substring(0, c.home_team.Length))
```

It demands that home_team starts with a string that is the result of cutting the first X chars off the word "internazionale" but if the home_team string is longer than "internazionale" is, then it will try and ask for more characters to be cut out of "internazionale" than exist in "internazionale", giving rise to this error

For example, suppose your list contains the dutch football team "Nooit Opgeven Altijd Doorzetten Aangenaam Door Vermaak En Nuttig Door Ontspanning Combinatie Breda" - it's about 85 characters long, and far longer than "internazionale" - so you cannot expect anything other than an error from attempting to substring 85 characters out of "internazionale".

Have a think about what you're expecting this code to do, and fix it up. If you're sure it's right, you're at least going to have to put a length check in on so that you don't attempt to substring more than 14 characters out of "internazionale"

Perhaps, if you want to return teams like "int", "intern" and "internaz" you can check which string is longer and then ask if the longer string starts with the shorter string:

```
c.home_team.Length < 14 ? 
  "internazionale".StartsWith(c.home_team.ToLower()) : 
  c.home_team.ToLower().StartsWith("internazionale")
```

Your question seems to say youre literally just checking if team names are equal to "internazionale" in which case I would say:

```
var fixId = fixtures.FirstOrDefault(c =>
            c.home_team.Equals("internazionale", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

What value you choose for StringComparison is up to you.. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparison?view=netframework-4.8 for more info on what the various options mean in the real world situations

Comment: You're right... what do you think is the right way to go? 'cause the only way I'm thinking is the length, which is of course not the properly solution, could you please suggest something? Thanks

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're hoping to do. You said "check if the team name equals "internazionale" in which case I would just do `c.home_team.Equals("internazionale", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)`

Comment: I'm trying to cover all the case studies, in particular could be team which are equal but have a name that is little different as my example above

Comment: For more targeted advice you'd probably need to edit your question and add some example team names that you consider to be equivalent to "internazionale"

Answer (score 2):

if home_team is greater in length than "internazionale", then you are asking for more characters from "internazionale" than it contains. ie. > 14 Change it to this:

```
var fixId = fixtures.FirstOrDefault(c =>
            c.home_team.ToLower().Contains("internazionale") || 
            c.home_team.ToLower().StartsWith("internazionale"
                                 .Substring(0, Math.Min(14,c.home_team.Length)));
```

Comment: What about if the values isn't `Internazionale` as Caius pointed out?